# How to chain two Firebase Filtering methods together

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an iOS app and I store location data in Firebase realtime database.

I need to get location data with lat-lon range, so I was writing a query like this but calling Firebase block `queryStarting` method twice consequtively.

My query in swift 3:

```
let wifiQuery = ref.child("wifis").queryStarting(atValue: northEast.longitude, childKey: "lon")
                        .queryEnding(atValue: southWest.longitude, childKey: "lon")
                        .queryStarting(atValue: southWest.latitude, childKey: "lat")
                        .queryEnding(atValue: northEast.latitude, childKey: "lat")
```

but I get this error;

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidQueryParameter', reason: 'Can't call queryStartingAtValue:childKey: after queryStartingAtValue or queryEqualToValue was previously called'

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property and a single range. If you need two ranges, you'll have to create two queries.

Comment: If you're trying to query by location, you may want to check out GeoFire: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc

Comment: I will investigate it. Thanks.